# SQL - Find the parent of the tree structure

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, inner-join

I have a table like this that parent_id=0 means the current row is the main parent:

```
---------------------
class_id | parent_id
---------------------
    10        0
    11        10
    12        11
    13        12
```

I want to get rows whose primary parent class_id equals 10
But when I use the `SELECT` statement it just returns one row because it has a Hierarchy structure.

```
SELECT class_id FROM TABLE WHERE parent_id = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a typical recursive CTE to walk the graph starting at node `10`. For example:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select * from t where class_id = 10
 union all
  select t.*
  from n
  join t on t.parent_id = n.class_id
)
select * from n
```